# How can I save an image in a directory with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, xampp

noob programer here. I'm doing a form and my teacher asked me to upload an image from any location of my computer and save it in a specific directory(also of my commputer). The code that i have only works  if the image is in the same location as my script. Hope you can help me.

Note: Also i have to save it in the database because i'm going to use it to make a pdf.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>
<form method="post" action="IConductores.php" >
<p></p>
    <label>Foto</label>
    <input type="file" id="Foto" name="Foto">
<input type="submit" id="Enviar" name="Enviar">
</form>

</html>



IConductores.php:
<?php
    $Rfc = $_POST['Rfc'];
    $Foto = $_POST['Foto'];

     $SQL = "INSERT INTO Conductores VALUES ('$Rfc', '$Foto');";

    $destdir = 'ImagenesPerfil/';   // path destination
    $img=file_get_contents($Foto);
    file_put_contents($destdir.substr($Foto, strrpos($Foto,'/')), $img);
```

Comment: Make sure you have **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in your form tag, then use move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Foto']['tmp_name'], $target); to the target file name

Answer (score 0):

add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag

```html
<form method="post" action="IConductores.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Uploaded file's name will be in `$_FILES["Foto"]["name"]`

And uploaded file location will be `$_FILES["Foto"]["tmp_name"]`

You need to use `move_uploaded_file` function like this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Foto"]["tmp_name"], $destdir.$_FILES["Foto"]["name"])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer!. But it  still not detecting the photo that i want to upload, it says: * Undefined index: Foto* on the line of move_uploaded_file().

Comment: And it also says * file_get_contents(Photo.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in*

Comment: add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag

<form method="post" action="IConductores.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Thank you for helping, the error was that i put enctype = "multipart / form-data" instead of enctype="multipart/form-data", now its working :)